# Search tables through radiogroup selection

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe3

I'm creating a Delphi XE3 application with OLEDB 4.0 connection to MS ACCESS Database. 
I have saved some informations on these tables, but now I want to develop a "Search content Form"

I'd like to have a radiogroup for the user to select how he wants to search the contents of each table on the database. Like : by name, by date or by age. And then have an TEdit for the user to dynamically type what he's looking for on that specific table.

I'm using TADOconnection, and ADOtables.

Comment: Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: First I'm trying to attach the diferent radiogroup options to a specific adotable

Comment: You define your rules and populate the radiogroup according.

Comment: @GeorgeVremescu how do I define those rules?

Comment: Just as in the answer you approved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have 3 columns `Name`, `Date`, `Age` you might try something like this. You need to have a timer with interval set to a search term writing interval (e.g. 1000 ms), then a radio group with 3 items, where the 1st if for name, 2nd for date and 3rd for age search term selection. Then you need to have a search edit box itself and handle the following events:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.RadioGroup1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  ADOTable1.Filtered := False;
  if Edit1.Text <> '' then
  begin
    case RadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
      0: ADOTable1.Filter := 'Name';
      1: ADOTable1.Filter := 'Date';
      2: ADOTable1.Filter := 'Age';
    end;
    ADOTable1.Filter := ADOTable1.Filter + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr(Edit1.Text);
    ADOTable1.Filtered := True;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This seems to work fine TLama, but how to show the result? for example a DBGrid

Comment: You've said you're using `TADOTable`, so just connect this table object through a data source with your grid.